# numpy create column after blank space

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have numpy array of size (6214,1), which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to create a column after each blank space, but whatever I try I am not successful.
How could I reshape this array from 6214x1 -> 6214x6 ?

Comment: i think you want to change the dimension of your array. then 1st flatten your array then reshape it.

Comment: first thing you cannot convert 6214*1 -> 6214*6 because it can equally distributed 1 column contain 6214 rows so if 6 col contain 6214 rows then it contain total 6 times 6214 value which is equal to 37284.

Comment: that's an array of strings.  you'll need to use string `split` to break each into a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original array contains strings. So all we have to do is to split them and convert to floats:

```
np.array([i.split() for i in a.flat], dtype=float)   # a is the original array
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

hope you get the answer from this working

Comment: That's not the problem.  He has an array of strings, which need to be split.